# Is it safe to have an opened port on my PC with a proxy server listening?

Tags: network, proxy, ports

I have a single port open for my own proxy server. All other ports are closed. Is it safe for my PC? Even if my port will keep getting bombed by hackers could my PC be exposed to them? There is no sensitive information going through my proxy so I don't mind it to be leaked, but I want to keep information on my PC safe. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to security.SE! There seems to be a contradiction in your question; you say *"opened port which is not used by any services"*, and also *"port open for my own proxy server"*. Is there a proxy service using (ie listening on) that port or not?

Comment: Yes, there is a proxy used for allowing captcha solving service employers to solve it directly from my IP address. There are no other services listening. Which data is in danger? Data being sent by proxy or entire data stored on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if a port is opened it's usually because there's a service listening on that port which responds using whatever protocol it is based on.

The first question is: What kind of service responds on that port, and what protocol does it respond with?

The second question is: Are there known vulnerabilities regarding to that particular service or protocol?

When the port number is uncommon, but open, the attacker send probes on that port to match the service behind it, and in case of positive responses, he tries to find answers to the second question.
Sometimes, he can find undocumented vulnerabilities using a technique called fuzzing.

Some others, when the source code of the service protocol is opened (opensource), he can find vulns simply by reading the code.
You should query yourself on the first question and keep in mind this easy advice: Always close unnecessary services and specific ports behind them to lower the risk of attackers gaining access to your computer by exploiting bugs in the service that is listening on that port.

Comment: 1) The port is open for 3proxy, so that I can host a proxy server. 2) Probably 0 known but there always could be some. Let's assume there is a vulnerability. Will attacker access only the information which is being sent via proxy? Or will he be able to access information stored on my PC?

Comment: @narra_kk It depends on what the vulnerability is. In the worst case (a "remote code execution" type vulnerability) the attacker would gain full admin control of your PC. How much do you trust that proxy application to be well-written and kept up to date with patches? ;)

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5762/3proxy.html) there were 5 known vulnerabilities for the last 13 years. 4 of them in 2007. But there is still a small chance so I guess I would need to change my setup. How about turning on DMZ for that PC while having all ports closed. Will it be safe?

Comment: @narra_kk Either the proxy application can be access from the internet or it can't... If you want to add extra protection, run the proxy on a different machine that has no valuable data on it, and place that machine in the DMZ. Basically a throwaway machine that you don't mind re-imaging if it gets hacked.

Comment: Yeah, but with a throwaway machine there's still a chance for hackers to perform actions on the Internet using my IP, right? In my case this is also an unwanted situation.

Comment: That's true, and also risk of the attacker using the infected machine to spread into your home network. Long story short: there is some risk in hosting applications and putting them on the internet. You need to decide for yourself what the right balance of *risk-vs-effort* is.

Answer (score 0):

While your setup is not fully clear I assume that you have a proxy server running locally on your PC which is reachable from outside the PC - because otherwise there would no need to open a port on the PC for incoming connections. Assuming that the hacker can reach your PC in the first place (i.e. when being in the same network, machine directly reachable from the internet or the specific port forwarded from your router) they might be able to use a bug in your proxy (which might exist or not) to execute code on your machine, i.e. this would not be safe.

Comment: I didn't manage to set up a proxy server without forwarding port from my router so I assume I am unsafe now. Are there any measures I can take to have the same security level as before?(before I forwarded a port and set up a proxy)

Comment: @narra_kk: The problem is that you have a proxy on your PC which should be reachable from outside - which means it is also reachable by a potential attacker. The proxy might have security issues which can be exploited. If you don't want this remove proxy and port forwarding.

Comment: What if I change (port forwarding + proxy) to (DMZ + proxy)? Or maybe (static NAT + proxy)? Will there still be a risk to be reached by a hacker? Or you mean that any proxy setup could potentially be hacked(not counting brute attack)?

Comment: @narra_kk: nothing of this changes *"that you have a proxy __on your PC__ which should be __reachable from outside__ - which means it is also __reachable by a potential attacker__"* and thus does not solve the problem.